# why is there a buffer for StreamReader Object at all?

Tags: c#, io

```
new StreamReader(new FileStream("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Testing/RedirectIn.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                           FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, 128, FileOptions.None), Encoding.UTF8, true, 5, false)
```

In the snippet above I specify the buffer size as 5.
I mean I underastand why you need to specify buffer size when creating a `StreamWriter`, but I can not Understand why do I have to specify it when creating a `StreamReader`.
I can only imagine that since I set it to 5 and I call this 5 times, the buffer gets cleaned up

```
        Console.In.Read();
        Console.In.Read();
        Console.In.Read();
        Console.In.Read();
        Console.In.Read();
```

Am I correct?

Comment: Sorry, I needed to ask why is there a buffer for `StreamReader` at all?

Comment: A minimal level of buffering is required because multiple raw bytes from the underlying stream can be mapped to a single Unicode `char`.  [`Encoding.GetMaxByteCount(1)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getmaxbytecount?view=net-6.0) gives the maximum amount to expect.  Beyond that it's likely that MSFT determined that a certain amount of buffering improved performance by reducing the number of disk I/O calls, but that the performance improvement became negligible once the buffer became large enough (apparently 1024 bytes was the number chosen).

Comment: Reading a single byte from something like a disk costs just about as much as reading 1024 characters into a buffer; really (or it did way back when I cared a lot more about memory and machine cycles)